# C: printing for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

Trying to complete a larger task in C, but for some reason this one small simple (or so I thought) piece of the puzzle isn't working.

I want to print 0 to 9, each on individual lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 9

int main()
{

    for (int counter = 0; counter == MAX; counter++)
        printf("%d \n", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

However, nothing* happens when I build & run. I've been staring it for over an hour...

*Nothing = `Process returned 0 (0x0)`...

Comment: Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And perhaps check that condition and think about its logic?

Comment: `counter == MAX`? I don't think so, since `counter` is initially 0 and `MAX` is 9. The condition should be `counter <= MAX`

Comment: Should it be `counter != MAX`

Comment: @JasonLiu For a loop iterating over a range, that's usually a bad condition. Especially if the iterations suddenly have to be changed to step over every second value (i.e. the loop increment expression becomes `counter += 2`) or similar.

Comment: I would advise to (re)read how conditions in for-loops work. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are absolutely correct and my previous comment is wrong on not only the initial cause of problems but the requirement. Because he wants to print from 0 to 9.

Comment: that's C++ not C , in C you can't declare variable in for loop! like for( int counter = 0 ... this is wrong , you should do the following int counter; for(counter = 0 ..... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you think the statement after the first semicolon in the `for` loop is the condition that stops the loop when it is true. Actually, that statement has to be true/non-zero to the loop to execute.

Try `for(int counter = 0; counter <= MAX; counter++)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my thinking!

Comment: you can't declare a variable in for loop in C language

Comment: @Badran I'm pretty sure support for that has been added in C11; if you try `for(int i = 0; i <  10; i++) printf("%d\n", i);` on various compilers on http://godbolt.org you'll find that GCC 5.1 x86-64 supports it as well as MSVC and Clang

Answer (score 2):

Change `counter == MAX` to `counter <= MAX`. So in this case your loop will run until counter is less than or equal to `MAX`

Comment: Counter is already `counter == MAX` ... and nothing happens

Comment: Read the answer again, you need to change it to `counter <= MAX`

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop will keep on running so long as the checking expression `counter == MAX` remains `true`. Which is never the case in this code snippet. You probably meant `counter != MAX`.

This would print 0 - 8 and not 0 -9. For that you would need to make `MAX` 10 or change the loop condition to `counter <= MAX`.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, fixed :)

Comment: Condition must be met in order to execute... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the middle area in the for is the condition for the loop to continue, and not to stop if it is true. While the condition returning `true` value, the loop will continue. In your case the condition have to look like this one: `counter <= MAX`. And in the whole loop:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter <= MAX; counter++)
    printf("%d \n", counter);
```

Comment: just change to `<= MAX ` since 9 needs to be included

Comment: @KyrSt I missed that part, you right. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that might prevent this code from running.

1. First thing is what everyone else have pointed. The condition is forever false in the conditional part of the for loop in

   ```
   for(initialization; condition; increment/decrement)
   {
       //code here
   }
   ```

the correct condition seems to be

```
    counter <= MAX
```

2. Second thing might be that you are using an old compiler in which case you need to initialize the counter at the beginning of the code before performing any other action. Initialization is not allowed within for in many old compilers. The place where it would be most suited would be right after the opening braces `{` of the `main()` function block.

Thus the best approach would be

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>    
    #define MAX 9

    int main()
    {
        int counter;
        for (counter = 0; counter <= MAX; counter++)
            printf("%d \n", counter);

    return 0;
    }
```